# Can you set the default program for a file type as a shell command?

Tags: file-association

I'm asking because I want some file types, such as eBooks, to be opened with a Chrome browser app.

Running Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 0):

You can with `ftype` and `assoc` commands.

Here is a good [article](https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) explaining how to use them.